# Having trouble getting a Mocked method to return null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm mocking a method using Moq and I want the method to return *null* but it's not returning *null* and I'm not sure why.

This is my setup code:

```
var mock2 = new Mock<ReminderRepository>(stubPatientRemindersDBModelContainer);
mock2.CallBase = true;
mock2.Setup(x => x.GetPatientEscalations(userName, patientId, startDateTime, endDateTime, new DataTable()))
    .Returns((PatientEscalationsDto)null);
```

When debugging, I was hoping that the variable assigned to `GetPatientEscalations` would be *null* but it isn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check the arguments being passed into the mock setup. if they do not match what is actually passed in when invoking the member it will revert back to the base call as you have `CallBase` enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the arguments being passed into the mock setup.

```
 mock2
    .Setup(x => x.GetPatientEscalations(userName, patientId, startDateTime, endDateTime, new DataTable()))
    .Returns((PatientEscalationsDto)null);
```

if they do not match what is actually passed in when invoking the member it will revert back to the base call as you have `CallBase` enabled.

Try loosening the expectation of the mocked member using the `It.IsAny<T>()` argument matchers

```
 mock2
    .Setup(x => x.GetPatientEscalations(
        It.IsAny<string>(), 
        It.IsAny<int>(), //this is an assumption. use desired type here
        It.IsAny<DateTime>(), 
        It.IsAny<DateTime>(), 
        It.IsAny<DataTable>()))
    .Returns((PatientEscalationsDto)null);
```

That way any arguments passed will match and invoke the mocked members to behave as expected.